# How to store the data and improvise these tables?

Tags: php, sql, database, normalization

These are my tables, first 'wallpapers' table which will be storing the unique details about all the wallpapers on the site, second one is 'wallpaper_categories' in which I'll be storing if it is categorized as wallpaper or just a photo taken which is tagged as photography, and the third one in which it will include what are the sizes its available in. the last two tables will be used for sorting data later like I'll be sorting all the wallpapers or all that are tagged as photography or all desktop wallpapers etc. my question is, is the a reliable way to create tables I'm not sure since there is duplicate data on the second and the third table, if not then how is this can be improvised. One last request is how can this be implemented in sql database like what value should I be storing in replace of the checkmark*..I'm sort of new at this, please help. Thanks in advance!
[image: Tables]

Comment: The term sql database is vague.  sql stands for Structured Query Language which is used by a variety of database engines.

Comment: I suggest a more normalized design.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the datatype, that depends on the database. Some provide a BIT datatype, in others you may want to use a CHAR(1) or a numeric datatype. Consider to add a CHECK constraint to restrict the column to two values and add a NOT NULL constraint.

Regarding the structure: If the sets categories and sizes you support are subject to future change, you may want to represent those facts as relations:

```
create table wallpapers (
    wallpaper_id int, 
    wallpaper_name varchar, 
    ... , 
    primary key(wallpaper_id)
);

/* All categories your system handles */
create table categories (
    category_id int, 
    category_name varchar, 
    primary key(category_id)
);

/* Categories per wallpaper */
create table wallpaper_categories (
    wallpaper_id int, 
    category_id int, 
    primary key (wallpaper_id, category_id), 
    foreign key (wallpaper_id) references wallpapers (wallpaper_id),
    foreign key (category_id) references categories (categories_id)
);
```

And similarly for the sizes.

That way, you do not have to change your database design every time you have new categories or sizes.

Comment: wouldn't the last table 'wallpaper_categories' be less normalized since there are duplicate rows of data?

Comment: No, that would be a normalized design. 'Duplicate rows' might be misleading. Have a look at, e.g., [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: am If I'm getting this correctly the idea of our last table 'wallpaper_categories' is having two columns one stores the wallpaper_id, and the other category id..which for example will be row 1: 1(wallpaper_id) 2(category_id) and since wallpaper can have another category row 2 would be: 1(wallpaper_id) 3(category_id)..is this how this table going to be?

Comment: Another question @Fabian, how about implementing comments on wallpapers..so I can have like a table called 'comments' which will have two columns namely 'wallpaper_id' and 'comment_content'; comment-content will store the actual comment, example: row 1: 1(wallpaper_id) sometext(comment_content), then row 2 would be: 1(wallpaper_id) sometext(comment_content). row 3: 2(wallpaper_id) sometext(comment_content) so on and so fourth..or is there a better solution to this? thanks a lot of your help..got bunch of knowledge from your answer! really appreciated..

Comment: @Vep Yes, the wallpaper_categories table would contain one entry for each pair of ids of a combination of wallpaper and category that had a checkmark in your original design. If, for example, no wallpaper had a checkmark in any category, the wallpaper_categories would be empty. If, for example, every wallpaper would have all categories, the wallpaper_categories table would contain every possible combination of ids of both tables (i.e., the cross-product). The primary key on the table ensures that a combination cannot be stored "double".

Comment: @Vep Second question: Yes, that is a common pattern to model a one-to-many relationship in the relational data model. The simpliest case would be CREATE TABLE comments(wallpaper_id INT, comment VARCHAR, FOREIGN KEY(wallpaper_id) REFERENCES wallpapers(wallpaper_id)); Notice that, so far, a comment would not have a key. You could add one, if you want, but that is not strictly necessary. It depends on your needs. For example, you could add either a single column id (e.g., comment_id), or could add a local subkey, e.g., comment_no, such that you have PRIMARY KEY(wallpaper_id, comment_no).